# Create a standard dataframe to receive data from other dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, concatenation

I have an algorithm that makes a request in different databases and receives a dataframe. However, these databases can be different from each other and send only a few columns, as in the example below.

[image]  [image]  [image]

Note that the column names of the dataframes are not standardized and it can contain NaN values in some rows. In addition, some columns appear in some dataframes and in others, they do not appear.

As I need to do operations that can concatenate the dataframes of the different databases, my idea would be to create a standard dataframe that contains all possible columns and start it with NaN values, as in the example below.

[image]

So, at each request, I would just fill the standard dataframe with the columns of the received dataframes. I thought about associating the name of the columns of the standard dataframe to the possible names of the dataframes of the databases through a dictionary.

```
dict{A: [A_1, A_a, A_y], B: [B_3, B_b], C: [C_c, C_w], D: [D_5, D_d]}
```

The idea of ​​the dictionary is because I need a practical way to update the possible column names to the columns of the standard dataframe, since there may be new names that I have not yet mapped.

In the end, my result would be both the following dataframe, in case I have requested the three dataframes above.

[image]

Or the following, if I only requested the first dataframe.

[image]

Could anyone suggest an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do particular frames have priority or will they all contain the same values as they do here?

Comment: No, in the end they should be concatenated. The values are not repeated.

Comment: concatenated on top of each other? Including your expected output in your question would be helpful in understanding what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I added the expected results to my question. I hope it got clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try creating a mapper that can be used with columns.map:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A_1': [1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan, 6],
                    'B_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', np.nan, 'f'],
                    'D_5': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', np.nan, 'f']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A_a': [1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'B_b': ['a', np.nan, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                    'C_c': [1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan, 6],
                    'D_d': ['a', np.nan, 'c', 'd', np.nan, 'f']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A_y': [1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'C_w': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6]})

alias_map = {'A': ['A_1', 'A_a', 'A_y'], 'B': ['B_3', 'B_b'],
             'C': ['C_c', 'C_w'], 'D': ['D_5', 'D_d']}
# Turn alias map into something that works for columns.map
mapper = {new_k: new_v for new_v, lst in alias_map.items() for new_k in lst}

# List of DFs
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
# Rename Columns
for df in dfs:
    df.columns = df.columns.map(mapper)

# Have Empty DF First with All Columns
default_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(alias_map.keys()))

merged = pd.concat((default_df, *dfs)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(merged)
```

`merged`:

```
      A    B    C    D
0   1.0    a  NaN    a
1   NaN    b  NaN    b
2   3.0    c  NaN    c
3   4.0    d  NaN    d
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   6.0    f  NaN    f
6   1.0    a  1.0    a
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   3.0    c  3.0    c
9   4.0    d  4.0    d
10  5.0    e  NaN  NaN
11  6.0    f  6.0    f
12  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
13  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
14  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN
15  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
16  5.0  NaN  5.0  NaN
17  6.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
```

---

With just 1 DF

```py
merged = pd.concat((default_df, df1)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(merged)
```

`merged`:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0    a  NaN    a
1  NaN    b  NaN    b
2  3.0    c  NaN    c
3  4.0    d  NaN    d
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  6.0    f  NaN    f
```

Comment: Your answer is almost there. The problem is that I may end up only requesting df1, and want to turn it into the default format. In that case, your code does not work.

Comment: Just add a default_df to the beginning of the concat with all the required columns. See edit.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A_1':[1,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,6],
                   'B_3':['a','b','c','d',np.nan,'f'],
                   'D_5':['a','b','c','d',np.nan,'f']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A_a':[1, np.nan,3,4,5,6],
                   'B_b':['a',np.nan,'c', 'd', 'e','f'],
                   'C_c':[1, np.nan, 3,4,np.nan,6],
                   'D_d':['a',np.nan,'c','d', np.nan,'f']})    

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A_y':[1,np.nan,3,4,5,6],
                    'C_w':[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6]})

dd = {'A': ['A_1', 'A_a', 'A_y'], 'B': ['B_3', 'B_b'], 'C': ['C_c', 'C_w'], 'D': ['D_5', 'D_d']}

#Invert your custom dictionary 
col_dict = {}
for k, v in dd.items():
    for i in v:
        col_dict[i]=k

#Changed due to comment 
df_out = pd.concat([i.rename(columns=col_dict) for i in [df1,df2,df3]])

df_out
```

output:

```
     A    B    D    C
0  1.0    a    a  NaN
1  NaN    b    b  NaN
2  3.0    c    c  NaN
3  4.0    d    d  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  6.0    f    f  NaN
0  1.0    a    a  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  3.0    c    c  3.0
3  4.0    d    d  4.0
4  5.0    e  NaN  NaN
5  6.0    f    f  6.0
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0
2  3.0  NaN  NaN  3.0
3  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  5.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
5  6.0  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

---

Let's just get first dataframe using slicing notation:

```
ldfs = [df1,df2,df3]        
        
df_out = pd.concat([i.rename(columns=col_dict) for i in ldfs[0:1]])
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, because in the end I would need to concatenate the dataframes. The final dataframe should be 18 lines, not the same 6. Also, I tested your script and it doesn't work if I only have df1 and want to turn it into the default dataframe.

Comment: But still, if I have only one dataframe, it won't work...

Comment: @LucasOliveira if you just have [df1] instad of [df1, df2, df3].  This code still runs.

Comment: It does work, but the end result is a dataframe without all the columns, because df1 didn't have column C. The answer by Henry manages to deal with that by creating a default dataframe with all possible columns first.

Comment: @LucasOliveira Awesome, glad you got your problem solved.   Happy coding!  Be safe and stay healthy!